# Outputting names and numbers to file C++

Tags: c++

My program is able to record all the names and amount "numbers" you input and display to the
screen, the problem I'm running into is saving all those numbers and Names to a file.

It seems that it only records and saves the last words and numbers you input into a file.For instance you type 4 names and 4 different numbers, it will save only the last name input and number and not the first ones input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct bank_t {
  string name;
  int money;
} guests[100];  // **guests name = maximum number of names to enter**

void printcustomer (bank_t nombres);  // **bank_t nombres = names**

int main ()
{
  string amount;  //** amount to enter**
  int n;
  int i;  //** number of customers **
  //int i=3;
    cout<<"Please enter the amount of customers";
    cout<<" then press 'ENTER' \n";
    cin >> i;  // **will take what ever amount of names you decide to input **
    cin.get();

  for (n=0; n<i; n++)
  {

    cout << "\n Enter the name of customer: \n";
    getline (cin,guests[n].name);
    cout << "\n Enter the amount of money: \n $: ";
    getline (cin,amount);
    stringstream(amount) >> guests[n].money;
  }

  cout << "\n You have entered these names:\n";
  for (n=0; n<i; n++)
    printcustomer (guests[n]);

  return 0;
}

void printcustomer (bank_t nombres)
{

    cout << nombres.name;  //** display the final names **
    cout << "  $" << nombres.money << " Dollars"<< "\n"; //** display the final amount **

    ofstream bank_search;
    bank_search.open ("alpha.dat");
    //bank_search.write << nombres.name ;
    bank_search << nombres.money;
    bank_search.close();    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that it only records and saves the last words and numbers you input into a file.

You're opening and closing your file for every record you want to write, and overwrite the one written previously!

You'll need to open you file in append mode (see [`std::ios_base::app`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)), or open it once outside the loop in `main()`, and pass the `ofstream` as parameter to every `printcustomer()` function call (which would perform a bit better).

```
void printcustomer (bank_t nombres)
{

    cout << nombres.name;  //** display the final names **
    //** display the final amount **
    cout << "  $" << nombres.money << " Dollars"<< "\n"; 

    ofstream bank_search;
    bank_search.open ("alpha.dat", std::ios_base::app); // Note the append mode!
    //bank_search.write << nombres.name ;
    bank_search << nombres.money;
    bank_search.close();    

}
```

Doing as shown isn't very efficient, since opening and closing a file is a relatively costly operation. A better solution would be to open the file once and append all newly entered records:

```
ofstream bank_search("alpha.dat", std::ios_base::app);

cout << "\n You have entered these names:\n";
for (n=0; n<i; n++)
{
    printcustomer (bank_search,guests[n]);
}
bank_search.close();
```

---

```
void printcustomer (ofstream& bank_search, bank_t nombres)
{
    bank_search << nombres.name;
    bank_search << nombres.money;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help really worked. It seems like a simple mistake but for me was very difficult to understand. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: 1+ Thanks for clarifying your example and taking some time for showing an efficient method. Sometimes beginners don't really know the differences,thanks for clarifying.